# Change asp:label with jQuery then access in codebehind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, label, code-behind

I know, crazy right.

So I have an asp label and I want to fill it with jQuery.  Later, in the codebehind I want to access this text for something else.

What I have is:

```
<asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="clickMe" runat="server" Text="Click!" OnClientClick="runMe();" 
   OnClick="clickMe_Click()" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

   function runMe () {
      $("#<%=myLabel.ClientID").text("here");}
</script>

protected void clickMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string isIt = myLabel.Text;
}
```

So if I put a breakpoint on whatever code follows 'isIt' definition and look at it, isIt="".  Is there a way to make this work?  I'm guessing since jQuery's acting on the html it is actually altering the  not the actual ASP.NET label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('#<%= myLabel.ClientID %>').html("here"); 
(This should work in all the browsers)
```

When I want to pass the value to the code behind page, I generally use a HiddenField and populate it using .val() in Jquery. I can then access its value in the code behind using HiddenField1.Value

Comment: Specifically your point about HiddenFields (the label thing didn't work).  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the value that you assign to label using Jquery will not be available in the code behind, hence you need to use hiddenfield. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `.val()` instead of `.text()`

Edit: 
Since ASP.NET controls are rendered with prefixes you may also want to consider the [ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector.

```
$('span[id$="myLabel"]').val("here");
```

Comment: I totally missed the most obvious problem.  You're trying to get the value of a `Label` control, not a `TextBox`.  `Labels` are rendered as `spans` and are not posted back to the server.  I can't remember if Labels have the `AutoPostBack` property, if they do set that, otherwise you need to make it a TextBox or hidden field.

Comment: Yeah, you hit the nail on the head.  I used Somya's HiddenField approach but I imagine a hidden textbox would do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

An `asp:Label` element in the browser is rendered as a `span` element. So, setting the value would not work on it. We should either set the inner Text or inner Html of the `asp:label` or `span` element if working with Jquery/javascript. Like below:

```
$("#<%= myLabel.ClientID %>").text("MY UPDATED TEXT");
$("#<%= myLabel.ClientID %>").html("MY UPDATED HTML");
```